# How to create a div over everything when hovering over a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, foreach, hover

As a beginner, I am creating a photo gallery. At the bottom I have thumbnails. Divs with the image as background created by jQuery with an array. Now I would like to create a 'bubble' with text. Something like the attached image.[image: example]

My array is created as follows and now I want to add the div on hover but would like it to disappear when the cursor is not hovering.

```
imagesData.forEach((item, index) => {
    $('#lower').append(`
        <div class = "box inactive" data-index = "${index}" 
        style="background-image: url(${item.photo}); background-size: cover;">
        </div>`)
    $('.inactive').hover(function () {
```

Now, what should I use here?

Comment: While we all recognize that learning is difficult the purpose of SO is not to give you "next step" tutorials, Read more about how the site works in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I have no points to add this as a comments but I think this will be a pretty good solution to you. As you mentioned in the question this seems like a tip that you provide to the image. then you can easily use [tipped.js](https://www.tippedjs.com) for your need.
Just read the documentation and do some exercise so you will be able to add the tips.